# How to animate area of a grid in CSS and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I put an animation on my grid which are modified by Javascript. I have this css definition:

```css
#lt-container-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 50px 40px auto auto 50px;
    grid-template-areas: "title title" "header header" "sidebar sidebar" "main main" "footer footer";
}

#lt-sidebar {
    padding: 0;
    background: #4f4e4a;
    grid-area: sidebar;
    color: #9c6c00;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
}
```

and I am trying to animate the **#lt-sidebar** by doing this on my javascript file:

```js
function manageMainPanel(x){
            x.classList.toggle("change");
            var width = screen.width;
            console.log("device width: "+width);
            if(width < 736){
                if(document.getElementById("lt-container-grid").style.gridTemplateRows === "50px 40px auto auto 50px"){
                    document.getElementById("lt-container-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "50px 40px 0px auto 50px";
                    document.getElementById("lt-sidebar").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("lt-sidebar").style.height = "0";
                    document.getElementById("lt-sidebar").style.transition = "all 2s";
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("lt-container-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "50px 40px auto auto 50px";
                    document.getElementById("lt-sidebar").style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("lt-sidebar").style.height = "auto";
                    document.getElementById("lt-sidebar").style.transition = "all 2s";
                }...
```

on my html:

```
<div class="lt-data-toggle" onclick="manageMainPanel(this)">
```

[image]

Comment: And? What is the problem? What do you want to happen?

Comment: I want to have a smooth transition of my div upon clicking a button.

Comment: `height:0` to `height:auto` cannot be broken into steps to create a transition nor an animation. Since you use javascript, you need to retrieve the height first of your sidebar  then set it into the style instead resetting it to auto.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
.sides {
  animation: 0.7s curtain cubic-bezier(.86,0,.07,1) 0.4s both;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50vw 50vw;
}


@keyframes curtain {
  0% {
    grid-gap: 100vw; 
  }

  100% {
    grid-gap: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value, read more here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers